# Knockout.js binding scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

What is the best way to share a variable between the `init` and the `update` part of a bindinghandler?

```
ko.bindingHandlers.someBinding = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) 
    {
        // declare something here
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) 
    {
        // use the variable here
    }   
}
```

I know for sure that I don't want to pollute the view model itself.
I could attach it to the element by `jQuery.data()` but that feels pretty ugly.

Comment: What are you wanting to share?  Knowing would probably give us better context on how to answer.

Comment: the amount of items currently shown in a special foreach binding. I want to make a binding that only shows the top x amount of items and adds a more button on the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The custom binding in knockout.js is only created once, so this means that if you store some local variable it will be re-used for every element where the binding is used. If this is not an issue for you below is one way how to achieve that.

Knockout binding requires that you return an object that has methods `init` and `update`. You can use object literal as you showed in your sample, but you can use other patterns, for example [revealing module pattern](https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/):

```
// instead of using object literal, use IIFE (immediately invoked function expression:
ko.bindingHandlers.someBinding = (function(){
     // define your local variables, functions and anything else you need
     // keep in mind that the same variables will be re-used for EVERY
     //element where the binding is used
     var yourVariable = 0,

         // declare init and update methods
         init = function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) 
         {
            alert(yourVariable);   // displays 0
            yourVariable += 1;
         },
         update = function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) 
         {
            alert(yourVariable);   // displays 1
         };
    // return object literal with methods init and update
    return {
        init: init,
        update: update
    };
}());    // execute the function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Next to answering my question, you've pointed to a great JS blog and a completely new JS pattern I was not familiar with.

Comment: The only disadvantage is that there is a lot of 'syntax fat', but I guess that's something you have to accept anyway with some JS patterns.